# the error of ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a program, whose files are organized as follows, The subfolder of `tensorflow_fcn` and `architecture.py` share the same parent directory. In `architecture.py`, there is a line of code `from tensorflow_fcn import fcn8_vgg`

[image]

The folder of `tensorflow_fcn` already includes `_init_.py`

[image]

However, running the program gets error message as follows

```
File "FCN/KittiSeg_pretrained/model_files/architecture.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tensorflow_fcn import fcn8_vgg
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow_fcn'
```

I do not understand why `tensorflow_fcn` was not identified by `architecture.py`.

Comment: How do you run `architecture.py`? From the same folder?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? Don't tag both.

Comment: Hi tamasgal, architecture.py is called from other program, which was invoked by python.  I have just trying to directly run python architecture.py, it works. Why does it have these two different scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.../model_files` is probably not in your PYTHON_PATH. In Python 3 you can use relative imports for this:

```
from .tensorflow_fcn import fcn8_vgg
```

Note the `.` .

This may also work in 2.7, although you should definitely upgrade if you're still using 2.7 .

Comment: If the relative import works, `model_files` should absolutely not be placed on the import path. You don't want the resulting mess of duplicate modules.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is related to the relative path of the file and module.
In my work, there is a subfolder "submodules" at the same level as the file, while subfolder "tensorflow_fcn" is under "submodules". So I use this form: 
`from submodules.tensorflow_fcn import fcn8_vgg`

This page may solve your puzzle
http://85608547.blog.51cto.com/2093443/1576759